# finding if a given string is a word, a character or a number in python

Tags: python, types

Given this string

```
random_string= '4'
```

i want to determine if its an integer, a character or just a word
i though i could do this

```
test = int(random_string)
isinstance(test,int) == True
```

but i realized if the random_string does not contain a number i will have an error

basically the random_string can be of the forms

```
random_string ='hello'
random_string ='H'
random_string ='r'
random_string ='56'
```

anyone know a way to do this, kind of confused, for determine  is its a character what i did was

```
chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
random_string in chars == True
```

i did another string to check if it was a lowercase letter.
also to check if its a word, i took the length of the string, if the length is more than one i determine that it is a word or a number

issue is how can i check if its a word or a number

please help

Comment: `in` works like substring, so your logic to determine if it's a character is slightly flawed (e.g. 'ABC' would be in chars).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings have methods `isalpha` and `isdigit` to test if they consist of letters and digits, respectively:

```
>>> 'hello'.isalpha()
True
>>> '123'.isdigit()
True
```

Note that they only check for those characters, so a string with spaces or anything else will return false for both:

```
>>> 'hi there'.isalpha()
False
```

However, if you want the value as a number, you're better off just using `int`.  Note that there's no point checking with `isinstance` whether the result is indeed an integer.  If `int(blah)` succeeds, it will always return an integer; if the string doesn't represent an integer, it will raise an exception.

Comment: `str.isupper()` and `str.islower()`

Answer (score 2):

Take your pick.

```
>>> '4'.isdigit()
True
>>> '-4'.isdigit()
False
>>> int('-4')
-4
>>> 'foo'.isdigit()
False
>>> int('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

To implement the logic your asking for, I guess the most pythonic way would be to use exception handling:

```
try:
  n = int(random_string)
except ValueError: 
  if len(random_string) > 1:
    # it's a word
  else:
    # it's a character (or the empty string)
```

To check the case, you can use the string method `islower()`.

Answer (score 0):

To gain more control, esp in case if you have some type of strings which inbuilt functions don't support, you can use re -

A regular exp like below to check if its a number -

```
re.findall(r'^[-]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*$', s)
```

and the following regular exp to check if its a string -

```
r'^[a-zA-Z]+$'
```

Please note that this is just for demo, you should modify the regular exp as per your needs.

Comment: How much faster is the numeric regex versus just passing it to the `float` constructor?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Even if we are lacking on speed(which I'm not sure of), we are gaining on flexibility.